# Showing Driving Directions in MapKit

Tags: iphone

is there any way to show the driving directions in iphones MapKit?

is there any way to get the coordinates and names of a route as an XML or in other formates  from google MAPs API ? 
eg , http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&geocode=&saddr=39.23232,-103.343433&daddr=41.23232,-104.344343&ie=UTF8&z=12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot use MapKit for driving directions.  It does not support this.

However, you could improvise a transparent view on top of MapKit and draw something, but nothing native to MapKit.

EDIT:  Here is a sample of drawing routes yourself:
http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65

Answer (score 2):

You should try Kishikawa Katsumi's project MapKit-Route-Directions is really well made and useful. You can find the sample project at github https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/MapKit-Route-Directions.git

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your view UIWebView. Than load to UIWebView something like this

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/directions-simple.html