# How to load Google Maps Faster in iPhone

Tags: iphone, google-maps, maps

in my iPhone application I'm loading the driving directions to a WebView from a bundled html page (because i can't find a way to load it directly to the MapKit), but it taking too much time to load, is there any better way to do so?  Like in the iPhone default map application

### code :

```
NSString *filePathString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"drive_index" ofType:@"html"];
NSMutableString *html = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: filePathString];

[html replaceOccurrencesOfString: @"varLocation1" withString:loc1
                         options: NSLiteralSearch range: NSMakeRange(0, [html length])];

[html replaceOccurrencesOfString: @"varLocation2" withString:loc2
                         options: NSLiteralSearch range: NSMakeRange(0, [html length])];


NSURL *aURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePathString];
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:aURL];
```

### and the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API Example: Simple Map</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=ABQIAAAAzr2EBOXUKnm_jVnk0OJI7xSosDVG8KKPE1-m51RBrvYughuyMxQ-i1QfUnH94QxWIa6N4U6MouMmBA"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var directionsPanel;
var directions; 
var location1="varLocation1";
var location2="varLocation2";

function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
  map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(location1), 13);
  directionsPanel = document.getElementById("route");
  directions = new GDirections(map, directionsPanel);   
  directions.load('from: ' + location1 +' to: '+ location2 );
  }
}

</script> 

</head>
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:divice-width ; height:350px ; float:top; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
<div id="route" style="width:divice-width; border; 1px solid black;"></div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this answer:

[Showing Driving Directions in MapKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397430/showing-driving-directions-in-mapkit)

It says a way to use the Map Kit (which doesn't include driving directions) and overlay lines directly on top. Here's the site they reference:

http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely see if you can switch to [V3 of the Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/).  It was specifically designed to load quickly on mobile browsers.  The only problem (and it's a big one) is that it doesn't support directions yet.